# Typescript. Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

```
  const element = getByTestId('code-entry');
  console.log(element);
  expect(element.disabled).toBe(true);
```

When I am loggin out element I can see the disabled prop over there

```
    { 'data-testid': 'code-entry',
       onChange: [Function: onChange],
       value: '',
       onBlur: [Function: onBlur],
       autoFocus: true,
       autoComplete: 'off',
       type: 'text',
       pattern: '\\d*',
       name: 'code',
       id: 'code',
       'aria-describedby': 'help-code error-code',
       'aria-invalid': true,
       className: 'sc-iRbamj dbWKbo sc-fAjcbJ hDxkek',
       disabled: true,
       inputMode: 'decimal' },
```

I've tried to cast it with as, but error remains.
Probably my appraoch is wrong.
Overall test is passing but the error is annoying me

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

I was casting with wrong brackets

```
  expect(
    (getByLabelText(constants.ENTER_CODE_TEXTBOX_LABEL) as HTMLInputElement).disabled,
  ).toBe(true);
```